# What do dashed lines mean in the schematic?

Tags: button

This is a "6-pin self-locking push button", but I don't know what dashed lines mean (those that are in the schematic).

[image: Text]

Comment: Can you provide link to this switch, datasheet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the solid lines are the connections in the "normal" or unpressed state and the dashed lines are the connections in the pressed state.  The datasheet may state this explicitly.

Answer (score 11):

[Here](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/26/APPM_S_A0001220312_1-2538056.pdf) is a similar switch with a different way to show the states:

[image]

I would prefer they didn't show the arrows on  pins 1 and 6 in OPs diagram, it makes it a bit ambiguous.

There are other similar switches in which the middle pin is the common rather than the diagonal ends.

If the switch is from some random Amazon, eBay, Aliexpress etc. seller I would definitely have them **in hand and tested** with a multimeter before releasing PCB gerbers to the fab.

Comment: Second the "test with multimeter" part.  "1" and "2" might have obvious definitions to you but they might have an equally obvious but opposite definition to the manufacturer.

Comment: @vir similarly possible that the seller substitutes something that looks like the original but is electrically different.

Comment: Very true very true.  And "electrically different" can also include "non-functional".

Comment: Btw, what is "non-sht'g."? The only word that comes to my mind would be rather inappropriate.

Comment: "Non-shorting". Most switches will have a very brief moment during switching where the common terminal isn't connected to anything. A shorting switch will maintain a connection at the expense of briefly bridging (shorting) the output terminals. Not very common, mostly found on slide or rotary switches.